# How is a direct swap transaction fullfilled by 0x

Tags: 0x

Looking at the direct swap example https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api-starter-guide-code/blob/master/src/direct-swap.js#L105-L113

Seems like the transaction is send to the chain's RPC URL which is different from any 0x endpoint. Then how is this transaction fullfilled by 0x ?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction object has a `to` field pointing to one of 0x's contracts. The node RPC that handles the request simply broadcasts the transaction to the Ethereum network for miners to mine.